# Logging into website with VBScript

Tags: javascript, php, vbscript, xmlhttprequest

Okay, so here's my problem, there's a webpage on our intranet that I must login to in order to gain access through one of our firewalls. I require this access the entire time I'm working but it automatically logs off every 60 minutes so I have to stop what I'm doing, go back to the page, enter my username & password & log in again. This repeats itself for about 9 hours or until I get off work.

I've been working on a VBScript that I could schedule to run every 60 minutes for me. Currently I'm able to do this via this **basic** script...

```
Const strID = "username"
Const strPswd = "password"

Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.Run("""https://00.0.00.00:0000/php/uid.phpvsys=1&url=http://www.yyy.net%2f""")

WScript.Sleep 3000
oShell.SendKeys strID
oShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
wScript.Sleep 1000
oShell.SendKeys strPswd
WScript.Sleep 1000
OShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
OShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
WScript.Sleep 1500

Set IE = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set windows = IE.Windows()

For Each window In IE.windows
    If left(window.LocationUrl, 5) <> "file:" Then
        If InStr(window.locationUrl, "http://www.yyy.net/") Then window.Quit()
        If UCase(window.locationUrl) = UCase("about:tabs") Then window.Quit()
    End If
Next
```

The above script works of course & I'm currently using it; however, the problem is, if/when the script runs before you're logged out then you receive an error from the script & obviously it won't run again for another hour. This inspired me to dive deeper into scripting. I began searching around for similar topics/methods, examining others codes, etc. just to get some ideas. My first attempt was to accomplish the same thing as the above script except completely hidden & without the use of 'SendKeys'. My goal was to put together a script like this...

Navigate to the page & then check the "heading" string...if it's = 'xxxx' then you're logged out so set the values for the username & password elements & submit them...otherwise, if it's = 'yyyy' then you're still logged in so Sleep for 10sec., reload & check again. I was almost certain this would work but with this script, no matter WHAT I looked for with `document.getElementById("zzz")`, I ALWAYS get the "null" error. It's as if no elements even exist & I've used every single `Name=` & `ID=` I can find in the source. (If interested, I can post this script as well but I ended up moving on to a completely different approach)

After the above issues I started reading about XMLHttp & sending the data this way instead. Using Fiddler I logged into the webpage like normal & was able to find the string with the username+password which get's sent to the server & tried writing a script to accomplish it. This is what I now have...

```
Call Main

Function Main ()
User = "myusername"
Pass = "mypassword"

'This is the string Fiddler revealed is being sent to server at login...
'"inputStr=&escapeUser=user&user=user&passwd=passwd&ok=Login"

'So I create this string with my information instead of elements values...
Credentials = ("inputStr=&escapeUser=" & User & "&user=" & User & "&passwd=" & Pass & "&ok=Login")

Set objXML = CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHttp.6.0")
objXML.Open "POST", "https://00.0.00.00:0000/php/uid.php?vsys=1&url=http://www.yyy.net%2f", False
objXML.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
objXML.Send Credentials

End Function
```

Using the above method, it shouldn't matter if I was or wasn't logged in, the data would still be sent & no errors would be raised. But this script does nothing, it runs, I don't get any errors, I'm still not logged in & Fiddler doesn't even show any requests having been sent or received after I run it. However, if I enter the appropriate information into Fiddler & then execute it, boom, I'm logged in.  This is the information I entered & executed & successfully logs me in via Fiddlers Composer under the Parsed tab...

With **"POST"** selected / The login pages URL  / **"HTTP/1.1"** selected...

```
Referer: https://00.0.00.00:0000/php/uid.php?vsys=1&url=http://www.yyy.net%2f
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: 00.0.00.00:0000
Content-Length: 68
```

Then in the "Requested Body" section I input...

```
inputStr=&escapeUser=myusername&user=myusername&passwd=mypassword&ok=Login
```

When I hit execute, you can see the request go through & the response come back & when I check on my end I'm logged in.

Hopefully I'm missing something simple that one of you guru's can easily point out or maybe someone has a better approach, I'm open to all ideas & suggestions because after 2 full days, I've gotten no where.

BTW, in case someone is just curious, or it's needed, or whatever, the relevant portion of the source from the login pages is below...

```
<body onload="loadPage();">
<table id="formtable">
<tr><td>
    <div id="activearea">
        <div id="logo"><img src="http://xxxxx.xxxx.net/xxx.png" data alt="Logo" width="100"/></div>
    <div id="heading">Firewall Access</div>
    <div id="desc">Please enter your credentials.</div>
    <div id="formdiv">

<script>

function loadPage() {

    if (document.login.user.value == '')
        document.login.user.focus();

    var errMsg = "";
    var respStatus = "Success";
    var respMsg = "";
if (respStatus == "Error") {
    if (errMsg != "")
        errMsg += "<br><br>";
    errMsg += "<li>"+respMsg;
} else if (respStatus == "Challenge") {
    var divUserName = document.getElementById("dUserName");
    divUserName.style.display = "none";
    var passwdTitle = document.getElementById("passwdTitle");
    passwdTitle.innerHTML = "";

    var divInputStr = document.getElementById("dInputStr");
    divInputStr.style.display = "block";
    divInputStr.innerHTML = respMsg;
}

if (errMsg != "") {
    var divObj = document.getElementById("dError");

    divObj.style.display = "block";
    divObj.innerHTML = errMsg;
}
}

function submitClicked() {
    var thisForm = document.getElementById("login_form");
    // hide the error div, just incase it was showing.
    var divObj = document.getElementById("dError");
    divObj.style.display = "none";
    divObj.innerHTML = "";

    var divTaLogin = document.getElementById("taLogin");
    divTaLogin.style.display = "none";

    thisForm.inputStr.value = "";
    thisForm.escapeUser.value = thisForm.user.value.replace(/\\/g, "\\\\");

}

function onClickHandler() {
    submitClicked();
}

</script>

    <form name="login" id="login_form" method="post">
        <input type='hidden' name="inputStr" value="">
        <input type='hidden' name="escapeUser" value="">        

        <div id="taLogin">
              <table>
                  <tr id="dUserName">
                      <td><span id="userTitle">User</span></td>
                      <td><input type="text" id="user" name="user" size="19"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                       <td><span id="passwdTitle">Password</span></td>
                      <td>
                          <div id="dInputStr" style="display:none"><br></div>
                      <input type="password" maxlength="40" size="19" name="passwd">
                  </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>&nbsp;</td>
                  <td><input class="buttonFixed" type="submit" id="submit"
                      name="ok" value="Login" onClick="submitClicked()"></td>
              </tr>
         </table>
     </div>
</form>
<div id="dError" class="msg" style="display:none"></div>


    </div>
</div>
</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```